# [NgRx]Is there any risk in registering the ComponentStore at the root level?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-component-store

I saw [the articles](https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-ngrx-component-store/), they put the componentStore at the root level as a global store, which is convenient for development and can work normally.

[image]

However, in the NgRx documentation, [@NgRx/Store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/why) is still used as an example if you want to manage global state.

[image]

In my opinion, it seems correct to regard componentStore as a global service, but it conflicts with the design concept of ComponentStore. I don't know if there are any objections. Do you have any opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not bothering to go down the ngrx route for anything, ever.

With Angular's architecture and its DI and singleton services and whatnot, the only thing you get out of ngrx is a headache and lot more complication in your code.

Why sub to your service and make a single request for new data when you could make 17 other objects for effects, and reducers, and whatever else it needs before... subbing to the service and requesting new data?

Whatever global service you want:

```
export class GlobalCacheService {
    private observers: {[key: string]: Observer<any>} = {};
    private observables: {[key: string]: Observable<any>} = {};

    public getObs<T>(key: string): Observable<T> {
        return this.observables[key];
    }

    public addObs<T>(key: string): void {
        if (this.observables[key]) return;
        this.observables[key] = new Observable<T>((x: Observer<T>) => {this.observers[key] = x;}).pipe(share());
    }

    public request<T>(fn: () => Observable<T>, key: string, returnRawResponse?: boolean): void {
        const sub = fn()
            .subscribe({
                next: (response: T) => {
                    sub.unsubscribe();
                    this.emit(key, response);
                },
                error: (err) => {
                    sub.unsubscribe();
                    this.emit(key, returnRawResponse ? err.error : undefined);
                }
            });
    }

    private emit<T>(key: string, data?: T): void {
        this.observers[key]?.next(data);
    }
}
```

This is actually taken from a base class I have in use somewhere, but I figure it would do the job for illustrating.

Usage:

```
private readonly cacheKey: string = 'someKeyThatShouldBeSomewhereSharedRatherThanJustInHere';

constructor(private readonly cache: GlobalCacheService) {
    cache.addObs<string>(this.cacheKey); // ensure it's initialised - probably should be done elsewhere.
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cache.getObs<string>(this.cacheKey)
        .subscribe((x: string) => this.onData(x));
}

private onData(x: string): void {
    console.log('got data from global cache: ', x);
}
```

Now, as I said, it's not really a cache because it's actually an abstract base service template thingy, but it had the extensible observable setup in it which is the crux of the matter.

Though probably `BehaviorSubject`s would be better for a cache because they will emit the last value to any new subscribers, whereas those plain old `Observable`s will only emit when told to emit, so not great for a cache.

As it's a base service it contains a request wrapper for, for example, http requests, usage would be thus:

```
export class MyService extends ServiceBase {
    public static dataKey: string = 'dataKey';

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
        this.addObs<string>(MyService.dataKey);
    }

    public getSomeData(): void {
        this.request(() => this.http.get<string>('someUrl'), this.someKey);
    }

}
```

Ostensibly, anything could be in that anon method, though.

and component usage, per above already:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private readonly service: MyService) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.someSub = this.service.getObs<string>(MyService.dataKey)
            .subscribe((x: string) => onDataReceived(x));

        // Assuming this component is responsible for getting/refreshing the data and the other eleventeen components listening don't, I dunno
        this.service.getSomeData();
    }

    private onDataRecieved(x: string): void {
        console.log('got data: ', x);
    }
}
```

So yeah, that's a lot of rambling for someone that wants to just crawl into bed, and it looks worse than it is because we're looking at all the base stuff.

Once the one or two files are in place, you're looking at one or two lines every time you want your service or component to tap in to that cache: an init call (unless its done somewhere at app setup (likely recommended), and a subscription... plus the occasional request call whenever a component/service wants to get fresh data for everyone.

Just remember that ultimately, the store pattern type stuff just means a single place that everything will go, to listen for and/or cause updates.

Welcome to observables in a [singleton] service in Angular. A basic concept involving a lot less effort (especially when done at a very basic level).

Comment: This can be extended to different topics: what is the difference between Store and ComponentStore, because I want to ask about ComponentStore.

Comment: I understand that RxJs can do all NgRx things, and it's easier because he creates fewer files, which is what I'm currently thinking, but I'll consider another point that, like the concept you've proposed, changing to another person would There is another way of writing.

Comment: When there are many members of the team, it is more important to have a consensus. The advantage of using NgRx is that everyone has common rules to develop, but I am still wondering if this is necessary. Not everyone wants to spend so much time just to have common rules

Comment: Thank you for your reply as I would like to hear more objections.

Comment: That's the crux of it - working with others. Using a library like ngrx gives you common ground out of the box, vs a more basic custom solution. The question is, do you get enough value, and enough efficiency out of using ngrx or the custom? Ngrx has a fairly large learning curve for any that haven't used it, and maintenance/additions are expensive because you have to do so much for one little thing. Learning curve for custom should be smaller (+ hopefully documentation!) and usage minimal because it's more targeted and less general. Second question is: what does the team as a whole vote for?